# Trouble setting a function parameter with dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, astronomy

I'm using a function called FellWalker to find clumps in a data cube.  The documentation here http://pycupid.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pycupid.html says that config[“PARAMETER_NAME”] = PARAMETER_VALUE is the way to input it into the function ( specifically I'm trying to use the configuration parameter FellWalker.Noise) but when I try to run the function

```
out_fw =fellwalker(cube, rms, velax = 2,config['FellWalker_Noise'] = 2 )
```

or any variation of that ('Noise','fellwalker_noise', etc.) I get a syntax error saying the keyword can't be an expression.  I'm new to dictionaries but I don't understand where I'm varying from what the documentation says.

Answer (score 0):

config expects type `dict`, so you need to build a dict with all of the parameters, then pass that dict:

```
config = {}  # Make a dict
config['FellWalker_Noise'] = 2  # add whatever params you need
out_fw = fellwalker(cube, rms, velax=2, config=config)  # pass the dict
```

Comment: Keyword arguments cannot precede positional arguments, so this is also invalid syntax.

Answer (score 0):

This is simply not valid Python syntax; if you want to pass in a dictionary as the `config` argument, you must do it like so:

```
out_fw = fellwalker(cube, rms, velax=2, config={'FellWalker_Noise': 2})
```